# OO Programming - Balance as independent Object in vending machine UML diagram, Why?

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

Hello I'm try to understand one example of UML to represent a System of vending machine. In this example are 3 classes **Customer**, **Item** and  **Balance**. The problem here is Why **Balance** is represented as independent Object. I don't understand why because I think that should be a **Customer** attribute. Could help me to understand why?

[image: Example UML Diagram]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is important to the modeled domain.

Think of it this way: attribute and association is the same thing ([Association Class vs. Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836933/association-class-vs-attribute)), only you visualize it differently.

In the very same sense you could have a class `Image` to which `Customer` would point, or class `String`  to which association `name` would point.

However since you are modeling a vending machine state, you care about who (Customer) is buying what (Item) with which resources (Balance).

p.s. (unrelated to question, but related to the model): generally don't add accessor methods to your models, they are superficial, and login/logout sounds to me like overloading of concepts

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Indeed login/out is not part of an User class, but of an Authorization.